# pyspark sum group by month and date using start and end date

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe of contracts: a start period, end period, monthly price. I am trying to get each month's total revenue.

Current data frame:

```
id      start_period   end_period     montly_price
1       2019-01-01     2019-03-01     30
2       2019-01-01     2019-06-01     20
3       2019-07-01     2020-08-01     10
4       2019-07-01     2020-08-01     10
```

Expected output:

```
period          revenue_per_month_all_ids
2019-01         50
2019-02         50
2019-04         20
2019-05         20
2019-06         0
2019-07         20
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have contracts whose `start_period` and `end_period` have a different month (if this is the case, how do you want to proceed ? Could you edit your question or comment this post ?)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

df.withColumn("month",psf.month('start_period'))
  .groupBy("period")
  .agg(psf.sum("monthly_price").alias("revenue_per_month_all_ids"))
```